# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class: Constructor returning without calling superclass constructor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, admob, proguard

When I build release version with proguard I get runtime error on application start (retraced):

```
2018-12-18 23:10:37.787 16077-16077/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs, PID: 16077
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class age: void com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers.<init>() failed to verify: void com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers.<init>(): [0x1] Constructor returning without calling superclass constructor (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers' appears in base.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers.packageManager(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.zzh(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.attachInfo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I think that it caused by admob initialization but I don't know why it worked before.
This error appears after dependencies update:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, I restored old libraries and services

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had used `assumenosideeffects` in my proguard rules. Like this:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream { *; }
```

Which caused a bug in proguard to remove superclass constructor calling from every class's constructor. To fix this you have to change it to this:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream { 
      *** <fields>;
      *** <methods>;
}
```

The `PrintStream` is a class that you want to obfuscate using proguard.
This fixed the problem in my case.